# Qt Creator as a debuging system for Linux embedded

Tags: linux, qt, debugging, embedded

In our system, we write the code on C++ without using Qt libraries.Actually, we write the on Windows machine, but finaly, this code must to be rebuilded for Linux Embedded machine. At first stage we did it successfully with Makefile-s, but "old style debugging" with gdb utility killed us. So I want to use Qt Creator to debug the application.
I successfully use Qt Creator to build all libraries and applications for ARM machine(of couse I have an ARM toolchain). But I cannot remotely debug the system.
I do not understand, what I do wrong.
The questions:
1. For system debuging, do I need Qt Libraries buld for ARM machine? (as I wrote above, I do not use Qt Libraries for my applications or for my libraries)
2. Do I need to redefine Mkspec for ARM compiler?

Thanks, Slava

Comment: Post your QT creator kits settings. This could help us to help you.

Comment: 1)If you want to compile and debug on ARM you have to refer to the SDK extracted from the correct toolchain. 2) Mkspec could be not important, it depens on your system.

Comment: Name: IP Module Kit(Embedded)   Device Type: generic Linux Device  Device: IPModule(device created by myself. Tested)    Sysroot: /opt/toolchain/arm-none-linux-gnueabi    Compiler: arm-gcc    Debugger: arm-gdb    Qt version: qt5(/usr/bin/qmake)  Qt mkspec: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspec/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++

Comment: Compiler: /opt/toolchain/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++

Comment: Debugger: /opt/toolchain/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gdb

Comment: Qt version must be set to your sdk. I mean under your sysroot. What is not clear is that all refer to arm-none-linux-gnueabi, but only sysroot has to refer to it. Compiler and debugger to a generic. What is your target? Are you using Yocto?

Comment: @ApterRostislav when you add info like that, please *edit* your question.

Answer (score 0):

You generally don't need Qt libraries for your system to use Qt Creator as a debugger frontend for your plain C++ program on an embedded device. *However*, if you use qmake as a build system, the associated Qt version must (roughly) match  your target.